# No such file exists while running Hadoop pipes using c++

Tags: c++, hadoop, mapreduce, libhdfs

While running hadoop map reduce program using hadoop pipes, the file which is present in the hdfs is not found by the map reduce. If the program is executed without hadoop pipes, the file is easily found by the libhdfs library but when running the program with

```
hadoop pipes -input i -ouput o -program p
```

command, the file is not found by the libhdfs and java.io.exception is thrown. Have tried to include the -fs parameter in the command but still the same results. I Have also included hdfs://localhost:9000/ with the files, and still no results. The file parameter is inside the c code as:

```
file="/path/to/file/in/hdfs" or "hdfs://localhost:9000/path/to/file"
hdfsFS fs = hdfsConnect("localhost", 9000);
hdfsFile input=hdfsOpenFile(fs,file,O_RDONLY,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The files in the hdfs are not available to the mapreduce task node. So instead had to pass the files to the distributed cache through the archive tag by compressing the files to a single tar file. Can also achieve this by writing a custom inputformat class and provide the files in the input parameter.